# Is it good practise to have multiple class definitions in one file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class-design

Is it good practise to have multiple class definitions in one file? or is it preferable to have one class per file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I prefer one class per file.  You'll never have to search for the correct filename because it is always the class name.

Comment: Okay but what about nested classes? Following the one class per file strategy would you then make the main class partial? Then you would have MainClass.cs and MainClass.NestedClass.cs ...

Comment: And? What's your point? In fact, I've often gone and made a folder for MainClass in that case, especially with large static classes. Private nested classes don't (always) need their own file, but public ones should.

Comment: I wan't trying to make any points, I was asking Tim how strictly he follows the one class per file strategy with respect to nested classes.

Comment: @ParmesanCodice Like Matthew, public nested class in its own file. A private nested class not because a private nested is only an implementation detail of that class.

Comment: As a personaly preference I tend to disagree with this approach. I don't believe all classes merit their own unit.

Comment: Shouldn't all classes *be* their own unit? I thought that was kind of the point of a class... and if you have a large static class that needs it's own folder, wouldn't that be a class that could need some refactoring?

Answer (score 6):

One class per file.

That way you can avoid having to merge edits when two people have to edit the same file because one is working on `class A` and the other is working on `class B`. While this should be automatic in any source control system, it's an extra step that can be missed which would cause problems.

Far better to have a process that didn't allow this sort of error to occur in the first place.

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually merge edits because two people are working on different parts of the same file. If you do, perhaps it's time for a new version control system.

Comment: @Matthew - agreed, but it's an extra step that isn't necessary and will cause problems from time to time when someone forgets to perform the merge before checking their edits in.

Comment: I can't speak for other version control systems since I use Subversion exclusively, but svn handles merges automatically unless there's edits to the same sections in the file (ie, two people edit line 54 of the currently checked in file)

Answer (score 5):

I do not see any issue with multiple classes in the same file, as long as the classes are related to each other.

If you have resharper, you can always use the navigation tools to find any class.

Comment: Not everyone has, or can even use Resharper (Express edition for example)

Comment: You don't need Resharper. Visual Studio e.g. has a go to class definition built in.

Comment: And I use it lots. I was just pointing out that "use plugin x" isn't really a good way of validating your opinion.

Answer (score 4):

It is generally best practice to have one file per class.

Some folk, not me, like to have more than more one if they are related and very very small in size.  Others might do this in a prototyping stage.  I say start and stay with one per file as does Scott McConnell in his discourse on Class Quality in his seminal book [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/)

To quote, *"Put one class in one file. A file isn't just a bucket that holds some code. If your language allows it, a file should hold a collection of routines that supports one and only one purpose. A file reinforces the idea that a collection of routines are in the same class."*

Answer (score 3):

I think it's preferable to have one class per file and to organize them in folders having the same hierarchy as their namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Most programmers would consider one class per file to be a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Usually - no.
Following practice "one class per file" simplifies browsing of solution.
Additionally if you have a big team of developers and source control tool that uses pessimistic approach (exclusive locks) - your developers will have hard time while working on the same file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is down to preference as you said.
I think you'll find most online examples/ most code is one class per file for easy management.

I sometimes put 2 classes in a file - only if i'm using the second class as an entity and it's only being used in the first class.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you ask because you've noticed already that it's considered best practice. Given the obvious benefits (and some less obvious ones mentioned here), why would you want to do it differently? Are there any benefits at all in multiple classes per file? I can't think of any.

Comment: You are right, I had always assumed it was best practice to have one class per file, but I seem to come across more and more code where that is not the case. Even code written by industry experts.

Comment: Industry experts are not necessarily experts at maintaining code.

Comment: It's not uncommon in demo code etc, where it's sometimes more convenient that way. With demo code, convenience trumps other considerations.

Answer (score 1):

**Usually** it is the best solution to have one class per file (with the file named exactly like the contained class).

I only **differ** from that if

- There are lots of small enumerations ->I collect these into a single file e.g. Enums.cs
- There are lots (20+) of generated classes/interfaces that directly relate to each other   ->Into one file E.g. Interfaces.cs
- There is stuff that is no direct functional part of the application and in close semantic consistance (e.g. everything you need for interop. Thats usually a few structures, enums, constants and a single class) -> That goes into a single file named after the interop class.
- Private inner classes -> Stay with their parent class instead of partial classes

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, i know devexpress hates it aswell ( It has some detection bad practives).

But i do have it sometimes, when its a very small class thats basicly only used by the "main" class in the file. Personaly i think it comes down a bit to taste, there is a balance between having 10k lines long .cs files or having to many .cs in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think in terms of it being a "best practise" approach then probably yes. However, really it depends on the project. I tend to group related code into separate units for example:

```
MyApplication.Interfaces
MyApplication.Utils
MyApplication.Controllers
```

I really think a class only ever deserves it's own unit if it becomes huge. However, if it does get to this stage, you should start to consider moving some code into helper classes to separate the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with most on this.  One class per file is ideal.  It makes it easier to see what's available in a project without having to rely on intellisense to discover types that are available in a given assembly.

I think the only time I ever fudge on the one class per file rule is when I'm defining a custom EventArgs class and it's related to an event that's fired from another class. Then typically I would define those in along with a delegate for the event in the same file.  I don't know that it's a good practice one way or another or just out of sheer lazyness??

Comment: You shouldn't need to define delegates for events anymore thanks to `EventHandler<T>`

Answer (score 0):

If you work on a very large project, too many files can slow down your build times significantly (at least with C++).  I don't think that rigid adherence to a rule is necessarily the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One Class Per File is my Preferred approach, it helps me get rid of any confusion later on... I tend to use a lot of partial classes though...

Answer (score 0):

As long as I dont break the 1000 line barrier, I'll stuff in as many related classes that makes sense.

Sometimes an abstraction may only be one overridden method.